Pytorch import issue with shm.dll
I have an issue with importing torch, and error dealing with shm.dll or its dependencies came up. I would appreciate any help on this! Thank you in advance!
I have tried to use both the CPU and CUDA versions, but neither work and both come up with this error. This is the error that I get
This is the dependency walker view

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there any progress dealing with the issue?
I am experiencing the same.
When I try to import torch, it just raises error saying that shm.dll or one of its dependencies could not be loaded.
Could this be connected to the CUDA version the NVIDIA driver is compiled with?
The display driver on my computer has CUDA version 12.3 (from nvidia-smi log),
but the pytorch package installed on my computer supports CUDA version 12.1.
If this is the case, where and how can I get NVIDIA driver that is compatiable with pytorch package? The NVIDIA driver site doesn't have options for CUDA version.

I got PyTorch to work although I had to download Anaconda and use a Python environment, but after I did that everything worked as intended.

But I am not using anaconda. I am using pip to install python libraries.
The newest version of pytroch was the source of problem. Pytorch v2.2.2 works fine.
I got solution from this page.

pip install pip install torch==2.2.1 solved my problemtorch==2.2.1 solved my problem
